# Explaination behind weird behavior with AudioTrack for Android

Tags: android, audiotrack

I am trying to output a generated sound wave with AudioTrack. However, the produced wave is not the same and I have run out of ideas of what might be the issue. See the attached images below.

I have not yet tried to run my code on another android so I can't rule out it being an issue with just this phone (Nexus 5 LG). Playing back the same sample from an iPhone and recording it with this phone produces a correct wave similar to the one shown in audacity below.

[Audacity showing the generated sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MmMW.png)

[Recording of the sound that is produced by the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGmYa.png)

Here it can be seen how the first part of the wave is correctly reproduced, however, shortly after the peak it appears to instantly disappear. If the length of the signal is increased the wave is reproduced correctly however which I also can not explain.

Relevant code:

```
public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
static final int AUDIOTRACK_BUFFER_SIZE = SAMPLE_RATE;

audioTrackSend = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, AUDIOTRACK_BUFFER_SIZE,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
short pcm16bit[];
short flushBuffer = new short[AUDIOTRACK_BUFFER_SIZE];
pcm16bit = Encode.encodeData(frequency, pattern, SAMPLE_RATE);
// This is the same array that I print to a file and import into audacity. Therefore everything "should" be correct up to this part
Arrays.fill(flushBuffer, (short) 0);
// I noticed that previous sounds were still in the buffer during consecutive playbacks. After adding this that behavior disappeared. If there is a better way of accomplishing that I'm all ears.
audioTrackSend.write(flushBuffer, 0, flushBuffer.length);
audioTrackSend.write(pcm16bit, 0, pcm16bit.length);
audioTrackSend.play()
```

If there is any more information that is required to answer the question please ask.

Thanks

Comment: What are you comparing? The plot in the app against audacity ?  How are you producing the plot in the app?

Comment: The plot in audacity is the same PCM sample which I transmit through AudioTrack. I'm wondering why they don't end up producing the same wave. The plot in the app is produced by recording the sound with AudioRecord, using Goertzels algorithm to pick out the specific frequency it is sent on, and thereafter plotted using MPAndroidCharts

Comment: I think I would be easier to help if you include the code that's creating your plot

Comment: And also the code that is generating the signal

Comment: The plot is not the source of the problem. When I record the same sample but sent from an iPhone instead it is recorded correctly. The iPhone also reports the same inconsistencies when recording the produced sound from the Android device.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the signal you are trying to play it is hard to say anything. But one thing I see is that the 5th parameter to the AudioTrack constructor should be the size of the buffer in bytes. `bufferSizeInBytes`. It seem to you use the buffer length.

Comment: So apparently this behavior was only present on the Nexus 5. It works as intended on 4 other phones that I've tried. I still have no idea what causes it but it doesn't seem to have a large impact atleast.